# how does memory allocation work in JS when assigning variable with primitive value to a variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, memory, primitive

I've been studying JavaScript language itself, and came up with a question.
What does it look like when assinging a **variable with primitive value** to other variable?

For example, take a look at the code below, and this is what I think happens:

```
var num = 30;
var newNum = num;

num = 50;
newNum = 50;
```

Step by step, I believe that in case of primitive values:

Before actually running JavaScript code:

1. JavaScript engine checks for variables declared before running code
2. then allocates memory for each variables declared
3. then puts the variable names for identification purpose
4. then initialize with value `undefined` ​

Once JavaScript runs:

1. it allocates primitive value `30` to location where its identification is `num`
2. it copies the primitive value saved at memory from #1, then saves it to other memory location where its identification is `newNum`
3. then, it allocates new memory space and copies primitive value `50`
4. and it detaches the variable name `num` from existing memory to new memory space allocated from #3,
5. It allocates new memory space and copies primitive value `50`
6. and it detaches the variable name `newNum` from existing memory to new memory space allocated from #5

So far, this is my understanding of how JavaScript allocates its primitive values with `var` declaration.

However, I've found some describes differently. They say, both variables `num` and `newNum` would point to a same memory space where primitive value `30` is located at. Then, once reassignment happens, they would each detach and point to new memory space where primitive value `50` is located at.

Comment: The main go to site when you got intermediate or better knowledge of javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#garbage_collection

Comment: As far as I'm aware all these specifics of the memory management are in JS unspecified behavior and up to the engine how they implement it. IMO. JS' specification of memory management is *allocate memory management when you need it, and release it when it's no longer needed*. The fact that for years all engines use more or less the same approach doesn't make it a definition of the language itself.